# Ошибка при отправке кода из PyCharm на GitHub

Tags: git, github, pycharm

Написал простенький код, и захотел его отправить на свой репо github, но выдает вот такую ошибку:

```
remote: Permission to NikitaPlatonov30/calculator.git denied to NikitaPlatonov.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/NikitaPlatonov30/calculator.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

В настройках PyCharm вошел в свой github, ссылка корректна, но почему то нет доступа. (Вкладки VCS у меня нет, у меня community версия PyCharm'a)

Скрин ошибки: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал логинить github в PyCharm и через логин пароль, и через токен. Пытался также отправить код через утилиту git в редакторе, но также пишет нет доступа

Comment: сори за глупый вопрос, но спросить все же надо, а аккаунты одинаковые? "NikitaPlatonov30" и "NikitaPlatonov" вроде разные

Comment: Логин и пароль при доступе к github посредством git не используются. Используется токен. Если пишет, что нет доступа, значит вход по токену не настроен или настроен не так. А еще лучше вместо токена использовать ssh ключ. *"Скрин ошибки"* - https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119/

Comment: дубликаты совсем [рядом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=The+requested+URL+returned+error%3A+403)

Answer (score 0):

У меня в диспетчере учетных данных была привязку к другому github из-за этого не было доступа к новому.

Если кому надо (**Панель управления\Учетные записи пользователей\Диспетчер учетных данных**) и удаляете привязку к github.